# How to use REST API services in azure Bot framework

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am using Bot builder SDK 4.0 with node.js
I don't wanna use Azure bot service api, instead  I will use my own node service.

Requirement :

1. Wanted to have a complete Custom UI/UX for my bot.
2. Single Azure bot application with many different bot clients running.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the BotFramework with the default BotFramework adapter, you will be using the Azure Bot Service APIs like the DirectLine channel. You can use the [BotFramework-DirectLineJS](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS) package if you want to build your own webclient for your BotBuilder bot.

Also note that at the time of writing, the BotFramework-Webchat package has a new version in preview which you can find [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/preview). This version is rebuilt from scratch and provides rich customization options which could be worth a try.

Comment: can you help me with the example.

Comment: My In tension is below.

1. I have created a chatbot registered in Azure. I wanted to create 3 more bot's without depending on the Azure(Don't want to spend huge cost on creating three different bots in Azure).
2. I wanted to create a 3 more bots and host it locally so that all three instances having same app id and password but all three are different.
3. I tried Directline but I am not sure how to Host a bot locally.
4. Also I wanted to have different UI for different bots.

Comment: It would be great if someone shares the example  code